# Submit Form not working for newly added <input> using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web

so I'm using Javascript to add new  elements to my form. However, when I submit my form, only the default inputs are processed and not the newly added ones. I'm using asp.net C# for the server side code.

[image]

[image: Html Code]

Html Code

[image]

Request. As you can see appShare1 and appShare2 are not being sent.

Comment: It is because your new input does not have any `name` attribute

Comment: Missing name attribute?

Comment: Yes Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` property is required.
So`<input id="appShare1" class="appinput form-control" name="appShare1"/>`